# Insert items from one table that do no exist in the other one

Tags: c#, performance, sql, sql-server

The insert query below must insert the items not present in the **Articolo** table by importing them from **Importazione**, and must update the items in the **Articolo** with those present in the **Importazione**. To summarize in **Articolo** the articles must be updated and the new ones included. The fact is that the two queries used by c # are very slow. How can I speed them up?

**Sql Execution Plan Insert :** https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryifseaOX

**C# Code:**

```
String QueryInserimentoNuoviArticoli = "Insert into Articolo(CodArt,Descrizione,CodMarca,CodEAN,Prezzo,PrezzoListino,UM,Fornitore,Importato) SELECT ArticoloMetel as CodArt,DescrizioneArticolo as Descrizione,MarcaMetel as CodMarca,CodiceBarreMetel as CodEAN,PrezzoNetto,PrezzoListino,UM,MarcaMetel as Fornitore,'ELETTROVENETA' as Importato FROM Importazione where ArticoloMetel not in ( select CodArt from Articolo where Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' ) and MarcaMetel not in ( select CodMarca from Articolo where Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' ) ";
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(QueryInserimentoNuoviArticoli, conn)
{
  CommandTimeout = 0
};
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

## Extracted queries

**Insert Query:**

```
INSERT INTO Articolo(CodArt, Descrizione, CodMarca, CodEAN, Prezzo, PrezzoListino, UM, Fornitore, Importato)
SELECT ArticoloMetel AS CodArt,
       DescrizioneArticolo AS Descrizione,
       MarcaMetel AS CodMarca,
       CodiceBarreMetel AS CodEAN,
       PrezzoNetto,
       PrezzoListino,
       UM,
       MarcaMetel AS Fornitore,
       'ELETTROVENETA' AS Importato
FROM Importazione
WHERE ArticoloMetel NOT IN
    (SELECT CodArt
     FROM Articolo
     WHERE Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' )
  AND MarcaMetel NOT IN
    (SELECT CodMarca
     FROM Articolo
     WHERE Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' )
```

Comment: I'm no expert in SQL so I'll keep my thoughts as a comment. Perhaps joining on a temp table with the results of the subqueries in the WHERE clause would be more performant? The missing indexes in the execution plan you posted would probably help quite a bit too since it's doing a *scan* on the Articolo table instead of a *seek*.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: This does not feel like real code that you have in a production like atmosphere, we could review this, but you likely would not get the kind of review that you are looking for, please post the actual code.

Comment: I am also not a SQL expert, and I can't be sure this is what you need, but you might look at [the MERGE statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this scenario.